# Distributed computing in a network - Framework/SDK

Tags: network-programming, distributed-computing

I need to build a system that consist of:

- Nodes, each mode can accept one input.
- The node that received the input shares it with all nodes in the network.
- Each node do a computation on the input (same computation but each node has a different database so the results are different for each node).
- The node that received the input consolidate each node result and apply a logic to determine the overall result.
- This result is returned to the caller.

It's very similar to a map-reduce use case. Just there will be a few nodes (maybe 10~20), and solutions like hadoop seems an overkill.

Do you know of any simple framework/sdk to build:

- Network (discovery, maybe gossip protocol)
- Distribute a task/data to each node
- Aggregate the results

Can be in any language.

Thanks very much
Regads;
fernando

Answer (score 0):

Ok to begin with, there are many ways to do this. I would suggest the following if you are just starting to tackle this architecture:

##### Pub/Sub with Broker

Programs like RabbitMQ are meant to easily allow for variable amounts of nodes to connect and speak to one another. Most importantly, they allow for transparency and observability. You can easily ask the Broker which nodes are connected and even view messages in transit. Basically they are a 'batteries included' means of delaying with a large amount of clients.

##### Brokerless (Update)

> I was looking for a more 'symmetric' architecture where each node is the same and do not have a centralized broker/queue manager.

You can use a brokerless Pub/Subs, but I personally avoid them. While they have tooling, it is hard to understand their registration protocols if something odd happens. I generally just use Multicast as it is very straight forward, especially if each node has just one network interface, and you can extend/modify behavior just with routing infra.

Here is how you scheme would work with Multicast:

1. All nodes join a known multicast address (IE: 239.1.2.3:8000)
2. All nodes would need to respond to a 'who's here' message
3. All nodes would either need to have a 'do work' api either via multicast or from consumer to node (node address grabbed from 'who's here message)

You would need to make these messages yourself, but given how short i expect them to be it should be pretty simple.

1. The 'who's here' message from the consumer could just be a message with a binary zero.
2. The 'who's here' response could just be a 1 followed by the nodes information (making it a [TLV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type%E2%80%93length%E2%80%93value) would probably be best though)
3. Not sure if each node has unique arguments or not so i don't know how to make your 'do work' message or responce

Comment: Thanks Liam! I was looking for a more 'symmetric' architecture where each node is the same and do not have a centralized broker/queue manager. But thanks for the suggestion! really appreciate it.